# Uncaught Error: Call to private method DbOperations::insertData() from context ''

Tags: php, json

When I'm trying to insert data trough the database its says "Uncaught Error: Call to private method DbOperations::insertData() from context ''".

My insert data PHP code:

```
<?php  

  require_once '../includes/DbOperations.php';
  $response = array();


  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

if (isset($_POST['airport']) and isset($_POST['location']) and isset($_POST['space']) and isset($_POST['flight'])) {
    //operate the data further//

    $db = new DbOperations ();

    $result = $db->insertData($_POST['airport'], $_POST['location'], $_POST['space'], $_POST['flight']);

    if($result == 1){ 
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['message'] = "Task Inserting Successfully!!";
    } elseif ($result == 2) {
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "Some error occured please try again!!";
    } elseif ($result == 0) {
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "Data already Inserted!!";
    }

} else {

    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing!!";

}
   }else {
$response['error'] = true;
$response['message'] = "Invalid Request!!";

 }

  echo json_encode($response);

  ?>
```

My DBoperation:

```
<?php  

class DbOperations{

    private $con;

    function __construct(){

        require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DbConnect.php';

        $db = new DbConnect();

        $this->con = $db->connect();

    }

    /*CRUD -> C -> CREATE */

        public function createUser($username, $pass, $email){
            if($this->isUserExist($username,$email)){
                    return 0;
                }else{
                $password = md5($pass);
                $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?,  ?);");
                $stmt->bind_param("sss",$username,$password,$email);

                if($stmt->execute()){
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 2;
                }
            }
        }

        public function userLogin($username, $pass){
            $password = md5($pass);
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            return $stmt->num_rows > 0;
    }

    public function getUserByUsername ($username){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();

    }

    private function isUserExist($username, $email){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0;
    }


    /*CRUD -> C -> CREATE */

        private function insertData($airport, $location, $space , $flight){
            if($this->isDataExist($airport, $location, $space , $flight)){
                return 0;
                } else {
                $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `users_detail` (`id`, `airport`, `location`, `space`, `flight`, `userid`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, NULL);");
                $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$airport, $location, $space , $flight);
                if($stmt->execute()){
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 2;
                }

            }
        }
    }




?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call a private method outside the class, that's not possible, you can read more about methods visibility on the official [PHP methods visibility docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

> Class members declared **public can be accessed everywhere**. Members declared **protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inheriting and parent classes**. Members declared as **private may only be accessed by the class that defines the member**.

You should declare your method as public instead of private if you want to use the method outside the class:

```
public function insertData($airport, $location, $space , $flight){
  ... your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call private methods or fields outside class

Either make the function insertData() **public** by defining it as follows

```
public function insertData() {
    ************
}
```

or call it from constructor using

```
function __construct($airport, $location, $space , $flight){
    $db = new DbConnect();

    $this->con = $db->connect();

    $this->insertData($airport, $location, $space , $flight);

}
```

run it as follows:

```
$db = new DbOperations($_POST['airport'], $_POST['location'], $_POST['space'], $_POST['flight']);
```

Comment: thank you. I'm already fix it. But when I try to fill the data to the database using html, he says the error occured  like the message in result = 0